# postgres on OS X (yosemite): cant get rid of it

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-yosemite

How do I get really rid of postgres.app and related DBs & Users on yosemite?

I uninstalled completely, also related libraries.
After reinstalling the postgres.app 9.4.2.0the users, templates, tables are still there?!

Background:
I totally messed up and need to start the DB and Users from scratch.
But after re-installing postgres.app I still do see my messed up templates and schema?!

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a "solution"

Since I messed up with brew and a direct install afterwards, brew also removed some relevant things... (as always). I re-installed with brew and will check my paths later, for now its working and rails stopped screwing things up.